# Is hand digging a 4 inch trench for PVC drainage pipe behind my gas meter allowed?

Tags: drainage, utilities, trench

I'm doing some work involving drainage in my yard. One of my downspouts comes down right next to my gas meter. In order to direct water where I want I'd like to run the line in between the meters feed pipe and the house. I COULD keep the schedule-40 pvc pipe above ground (but it'd probably have to be black or I'd get an HOA nasty-gram for being too noticable) until I'm well clear of the gas meter, but I'd like it to be protected from sun damage and hail if possible.

Can I dig between the gas meter supply line and my house? I would do the work within 18 inches with a hand held garden trowel and then loosely cover the pipe with a thin layer of dirt and mulch.

Pictured: I'd like to dig a shallow trench -- just enough to bury a pipe and cover it with some landscaping fabric and mulch to provide UV protection

Edit: Just a note on the existing corrugated piping -- it's full of silt and I have no idea of where it comes up. I'm considering abandoning it for smooth PVC that can be easily washed out.

[image: Area to be excavated]

Comment: To be fair I could just wait a few years and the trench will dig itself, but I'd rather not deal with that :)

Comment: Most places require marking of the line paths before digging, usually free.  I would contact your local gas company to be sure, but it should be allowed, and if hand digging only, they might forego the marking requirement.  Know where your electric wires are, even hand shovels can find them shocking.

Comment: Most utilities require hand digging close to their lines anyway, so IMO you're good to go.  (Miss Utility will typically only mark public property anyway, and more and more utils are putting responsibility for their lines on private property on the onus of the property owner, so they'd really only mark up to your property line.)